# using HttpServlet to generate html-img source image -> how to request via POST?

Tags: html, servlets, image

I use a HttpServlet to generate an html image dependent on multiple IDs like this:

```
<img src="./someServlet?ids=123,124,125,126[...]" alt=""/>
```

`someServlet` extends from `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` overwriting the `doGet()`and `doPost()` methods. It sets the response contenttype to `img/png` and uses the response outputstream to commit the generated image to the view.

The servlet mapping is done in `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>        
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.package.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>        
    <servlet-name>SomeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/someServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**My question:** How do I send the request above via POST instead of GET? I tried surrounding it by the `<form>` tag setting the method to POST, but as expected, it didn't work.

EDIT: I need this because my request (with 5-10 UUIDS) exceeds the limit of a GET request

Comment: Why do you want to request the image by POST?

Comment: I want to use POST, because the get parameter length is limited. I commit 5-10 UUIds as a parameter, which exceeds the length of a GET request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change an `<img>` element to send a POST request instead of GET. This makes no sense.

As per the comment on the question the query string length limit seems to be the main reason:

> *I want to use POST, because the get parameter length is limited. I commit 5-10 UUIds as a parameter, which exceeds the length of a GET request.*

Just pass it as part of URL instead, as path info. So, instead of

```
<img src="someServlet?id1=123&id2=234&id3=345&id4=456&id5=567" alt=""/>
```

use

```
<img src="someServlet/123/234/345/456/567" alt=""/>
```

You only need to change your servlet's URL pattern to

```
<url-pattern>/someServlet/*</url-pattern>
```

and change the way to obtain the IDs as follows

```
String[] ids = request.getPathInfo().substring(1).split("/");
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. If i understand you correctly your idea is to save bytes. But im doing this already. I should have mentioned that in my start post, sorry. My call actually looks like this: `<img src="./someServlet?ids=123,124,125>` but it's still too long :(        edit: or can the path be longer than 256 bytes?

Comment: You don't understand me. The problem was the maximum length of the query string. That's the part after `?` in URL. I've proposed a solution which gets rid of the query string altogether and goes purely through the URL path info. You only need to change the servlet code to obtain it as path info instead of request parameter. Re-read the answer once again.